# How to control Magento block rendering order (not position)

Tags: php, magento, layout, block, magento-1.5

On our Magento store we have "featured" pages that are basically product collections where a certain "featured" attribute has been set.  I use CMS pages for this along with a custom module with custom block classes to display the products.  This works great.  I'm working now on adding Magento's layered navigation to these pages.  This has proven more difficult that I thought, mostly due to the fact that the Layered Navigation is dependent on the **current_category**.  I have been able to work around that by creating my own layered navigation block and my own Layer class.  I now have it working, but I've run into issues with the order in which the block content is rendered.

When Magento renders the layout, it seems to be rendering the Left structural block first, which contains the category tree and the layered navigation block.  Unfortunately, my customized layered navigation block depends on the product list within the content block.  When the layered navigation block gets rendered, the filtered product collection has not yet been created.  This results in an empty list of filterable attributes, so the layered navigation block only shows the category list.

I have been able to work around THAT problem by moving the block definition in my layout XML file so it happens AFTER the content block is created.  While this works, it's not the elegant solution I was hoping for.  I have a custom layout handle that I created that handles all the shared blocks for all "featured" pages.  For every "featured" page, I call `<update handle="featured_default">`.  Initially, what I tried to do was to put my layered navigation block definition within the **featured_default** handle, but this resulted in the problem above (i.e. the product collection wasn't ready yet).  By putting it *AFTER* the product list block definition it renders correctly.  But this means I have to put it in *EVERY* layout update for *ALL* featured pages.  As I said, not the elegant solution I was hoping for.

So this brings me to my question...if you're still with me.  Is it possible to control the *rendering* order of blocks?  I know you can control the *placement* of blocks using the **before** and **after** attributes in the block definition, but that only controls their position within their parent block.  What I want to do is render the output of the layered navigation block *AFTER* the content block has been rendered.  Is this possible?

A follow-up question would be: Am I doing this right?  Given what I'm trying to accomplish, are there better solutions to this problem?  Most of the information I've found online about putting the Layered Navigation block on CMS pages shows you how to set a category ID for use with the layered nav block, but that's not what I have.  The products can be in different categories..the only thing they have in common is that they have a particular attribute value set to **true**.

Sorry for the long winded question.  I hope this makes sense.  If you need to see any of my code, please let me know and I'll post whatever you need.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't have an answer for you but I feel if the block order has an effect then you have too much business logic in the view layer, that should be in the model or controller layers instead.  Just because that was how some other dev did it does not make it ok.

Comment: You very well may be right, clockworkgeek.  I am relatively new to Magento and much of the code I wrote early on could use an overhaul.  My "featured" module is definitely heavy on the "view" side of things.  When the block is configured in the layout or on a CMS page, you pass a parameter indicating the attribute on which the product collection is filtered.  Because of this, the only way that I know for the product collection to get generated is during block instantiation, which I guess is the "view layer".  If you have any recommendations for better ways to handle it I'm all ears (eyes) :)

Answer (score 0):

In Magento the `before="child.block.name"` and `after="child.block.name"` attributes are used to define the order of blocks. If those attributes are not specified then the blocks will render in the order that Magento reads them.

For example

Move Cart sidebar block from left to right:

```
<reference name="left">
    <action method="unsetChild"><alias>cart_sidebar</alias></action>
</reference>
<reference name="right">
    <action method="insert"><blockName>cart_sidebar</blockName></action>
</reference>
```

- blockName: is your block unique name.
- siblingName:  is an block unique name, that is already exists in
  insertion target block.
- after: is a boolean identifier of block position. If equals to 1,
  then the block will be added after siblingName or in the bottom of
  the children list if siblingName is empty
- alias: is the alias of your block, if it is empty the blockName will
  be used.